# How to get a T/F column with specific conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks a little something like this:
[image]

I need to find whether a certain value exists for each category ('A', 'B', 'C'). Let's say, for example, I have a list with the letters [c, d, e]. I want to create a column where it would tell me for each category, whether these values are in the category. Essentially, the final product should look something like this:

[image]

When I try an if statement of any sort to compare values, I get this warning: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

How can I avoid this and get my desired dataframe?

Comment: When you use `if`, it applies to the column writ large. It returns a sequence. You need to either apply your logic to each row (eg `np.where`) or otherwise reduce the dimensionality of your true-false sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```py
lst = ['c', 'd', 'e']
out = (df['col2'].isin(lst)
       .groupby(df['col1'], as_index=False).any())
```